# fullPage.js scrolling on top of select box element in IE and Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fullpage.js

Basically I've encountered a problem with `fullPage.js` scrolling when a select tag is open.

This only happens in **IE** (all versions) and only **Firefox** in a mac.

I don't know if this is an issue or if I'm simply forgetting something.

What have I tried :

1. Adding `normalScrollElements` to the `select` or `form`.
2. Disabling `fullPage` scroll when the user is in the `form` or `select`

Both of them didn't work.

### 1st try:

**Codepen**: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/doGEgo

Snippet:

**Doesn't work properly here**

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#fullpage').fullpage({
        anchors: ["contact-form","contact"],
        navigation: true,
        scrollOverflow: true,
        navigationPosition: 'right',
        navigationTooltips: ["Form","Meh"],
        responsive: 991,
        easingcss3: 'cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.320, 1.275)',
        paddingTop: '110px',
        normalScrollElements: '#country'
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="fullpage">
    <div class="section">
        Some section
        <form action="">
            <select name="country" id="country" class="form-control" style="margin-top:20px;" data-fv-field="country">
                <option selected="" disabled="">Country</option>
                <optgroup label="Frequent Visitors">
                    <option value="France">France</option>
                    <option value="Germany">Germany</option>
                    <option value="Italy">Italy</option>
                    <option value="Norway">Norway</option>
                    <option value="Spain">Spain</option>
                    <option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option>
                    <option value="United States">United States</option>
                </optgroup>
                <optgroup label="All Countries">
                    <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
                    <option value="Albania">Albania</option>
                    <option value="Algeria">Algeria</option>
                    <option value="American Samoa">American Samoa</option>
                    <option value="Andorra">Andorra</option>
                    <option value="Angola">Angola</option>
                    <option value="Anguilla">Anguilla</option>
                    <option value="Antarctica">Antarctica</option>
                    <option value="Antigua and Barbuda">Antigua and Barbuda</option>
                    <option value="Argentina">Argentina</option>
                    <option value="Armenia">Armenia</option>
                    <option value="Aruba">Aruba</option>
                    <option value="Australia">Australia</option>
                    <option value="Austria">Austria</option>
                    <option value="Azerbaijan">Azerbaijan</option>
                    <option value="Bahamas">Bahamas</option>
                    <option value="Bahrain">Bahrain</option>
                    <option value="Bangladesh">Bangladesh</option>
                    <option value="Barbados">Barbados</option>
                    <option value="Belarus">Belarus</option>
                    <option value="Belgium">Belgium</option>
                    <option value="Belize">Belize</option>
                    <option value="Benin">Benin</option>
                    <option value="Bermuda">Bermuda</option>
                    <option value="Bhutan">Bhutan</option>
                    <option value="Bolivia">Bolivia</option>
                    <option value="Bosnia and Herzegovina">Bosnia and Herzegovina</option>
                    <option value="Botswana">Botswana</option>
                    <option value="Bouvet Island">Bouvet Island</option>
                    <option value="Brazil">Brazil</option>
                    <option value="British Indian Ocean Territory">British Indian Ocean Territory</option>
                    <option value="Brunei Darussalam">Brunei Darussalam</option>
                    <option value="Bulgaria">Bulgaria</option>
                    <option value="Burkina Faso">Burkina Faso</option>
                    <option value="Burundi">Burundi</option>
                    <option value="Cambodia">Cambodia</option>
                    <option value="Cameroon">Cameroon</option>
                    <option value="Canada">Canada</option>
                    <option value="Cape Verde">Cape Verde</option>
                    <option value="Cayman Islands">Cayman Islands</option>
                    <option value="Central African Republic">Central African Republic</option>
                    <option value="Chad">Chad</option>
                    <option value="Chile">Chile</option>
                    <option value="China">China</option>
                    <option value="Christmas Island">Christmas Island</option>
                    <option value="Cocos (Keeling) Islands">Cocos (Keeling) Islands</option>
                    <option value="Colombia">Colombia</option>
                    <option value="Comoros">Comoros</option>
                    <option value="Congo">Congo</option>
                    <option value="Congo, the Democratic Republic of the">Congo, the Democratic Republic of the</option>
                    <option value="Cook Islands">Cook Islands</option>
                    <option value="Costa Rica">Costa Rica</option>
                    <option value="Cote D'Ivoire">Cote D'Ivoire</option>
                    <option value="Croatia">Croatia</option>
                    <option value="Cuba">Cuba</option>
                    <option value="Cyprus">Cyprus</option>
                    <option value="Czech Republic">Czech Republic</option>
                    <option value="Denmark">Denmark</option>
                    <option value="Djibouti">Djibouti</option>
                    <option value="Dominica">Dominica</option>
                    <option value="Dominican Republic">Dominican Republic</option>
                    <option value="Ecuador">Ecuador</option>
                    <option value="Egypt">Egypt</option>
                    <option value="El Salvador">El Salvador</option>
                    <option value="Equatorial Guinea">Equatorial Guinea</option>
                    <option value="Eritrea">Eritrea</option>
                    <option value="Estonia">Estonia</option>
                    <option value="Ethiopia">Ethiopia</option>
                    <option value="Falkland Islands (Malvinas)">Falkland Islands (Malvinas)</option>
                    <option value="Faroe Islands">Faroe Islands</option>
                    <option value="Fiji">Fiji</option>
                    <option value="Finland">Finland</option>
                    <option value="French Guiana">French Guiana</option>
                    <option value="French Polynesia">French Polynesia</option>
                    <option value="French Southern Territories">French Southern Territories</option>
                    <option value="Gabon">Gabon</option>
                    <option value="Gambia">Gambia</option>
                    <option value="Georgia">Georgia</option>
                    <option value="Ghana">Ghana</option>
                    <option value="Gibraltar">Gibraltar</option>
                    <option value="Greece">Greece</option>
                    <option value="Greenland">Greenland</option>
                    <option value="Grenada">Grenada</option>
                    <option value="Guadeloupe">Guadeloupe</option>
                    <option value="Guam">Guam</option>
                    <option value="Guatemala">Guatemala</option>
                    <option value="Guinea">Guinea</option>
                    <option value="Guinea-Bissau">Guinea-Bissau</option>
                    <option value="Guyana">Guyana</option>
                    <option value="Haiti">Haiti</option>
                    <option value="Heard Island and Mcdonald Islands">Heard Island and Mcdonald Islands</option>
                    <option value="Holy See (Vatican City State)">Holy See (Vatican City State)</option>
                    <option value="Honduras">Honduras</option>
                    <option value="Hong Kong">Hong Kong</option>
                    <option value="Hungary">Hungary</option>
                    <option value="Iceland">Iceland</option>
                    <option value="India">India</option>
                    <option value="Indonesia">Indonesia</option>
                    <option value="Iran, Islamic Republic of">Iran, Islamic Republic of</option>
                    <option value="Iraq">Iraq</option>
                    <option value="Ireland">Ireland</option>
                    <option value="Israel">Israel</option>
                    <option value="Jamaica">Jamaica</option>
                    <option value="Japan">Japan</option>
                    <option value="Jordan">Jordan</option>
                    <option value="Kazakhstan">Kazakhstan</option>
                    <option value="Kenya">Kenya</option>
                    <option value="Kiribati">Kiribati</option>
                    <option value="Korea, Democratic People's Republic of">Korea, Democratic People's Republic of</option>
                    <option value="Korea, Republic of">Korea, Republic of</option>
                    <option value="Kuwait">Kuwait</option>
                    <option value="Kyrgyzstan">Kyrgyzstan</option>
                    <option value="Lao People's Democratic Republic">Lao People's Democratic Republic</option>
                    <option value="Latvia">Latvia</option>
                    <option value="Lebanon">Lebanon</option>
                    <option value="Lesotho">Lesotho</option>
                    <option value="Liberia">Liberia</option>
                    <option value="Libyan Arab Jamahiriya">Libyan Arab Jamahiriya</option>
                    <option value="Liechtenstein">Liechtenstein</option>
                    <option value="Lithuania">Lithuania</option>
                    <option value="Luxembourg">Luxembourg</option>
                    <option value="Macao">Macao</option>
                    <option value="Macedonia, the Former Yugoslav Republic of">Macedonia, the Former Yugoslav Republic of</option>
                    <option value="Madagascar">Madagascar</option>
                    <option value="Malawi">Malawi</option>
                    <option value="Malaysia">Malaysia</option>
                    <option value="Maldives">Maldives</option>
                    <option value="Mali">Mali</option>
                    <option value="Malta">Malta</option>
                    <option value="Marshall Islands">Marshall Islands</option>
                    <option value="Martinique">Martinique</option>
                    <option value="Mauritania">Mauritania</option>
                    <option value="Mauritius">Mauritius</option>
                    <option value="Mayotte">Mayotte</option>
                    <option value="Mexico">Mexico</option>
                    <option value="Micronesia, Federated States of">Micronesia, Federated States of</option>
                    <option value="Moldova, Republic of">Moldova, Republic of</option>
                    <option value="Monaco">Monaco</option>
                    <option value="Mongolia">Mongolia</option>
                    <option value="Montserrat">Montserrat</option>
                    <option value="Morocco">Morocco</option>
                    <option value="Mozambique">Mozambique</option>
                    <option value="Myanmar">Myanmar</option>
                    <option value="Namibia">Namibia</option>
                    <option value="Nauru">Nauru</option>
                    <option value="Nepal">Nepal</option>
                    <option value="Netherlands">Netherlands</option>
                    <option value="Netherlands Antilles">Netherlands Antilles</option>
                    <option value="New Caledonia">New Caledonia</option>
                    <option value="New Zealand">New Zealand</option>
                    <option value="Nicaragua">Nicaragua</option>
                    <option value="Niger">Niger</option>
                    <option value="Nigeria">Nigeria</option>
                    <option value="Niue">Niue</option>
                    <option value="Norfolk Island">Norfolk Island</option>
                    <option value="Northern Mariana Islands">Northern Mariana Islands</option>
                    <option value="Oman">Oman</option>
                    <option value="Pakistan">Pakistan</option>
                    <option value="Palau">Palau</option>
                    <option value="Palestinian Territory, Occupied">Palestinian Territory, Occupied</option>
                    <option value="Panama">Panama</option>
                    <option value="Saint Lucia">Saint Lucia</option>
                    <option value="Saint Pierre and Miquelon">Saint Pierre and Miquelon</option>
                    <option value="Saint Vincent and the Grenadines">Saint Vincent and the Grenadines</option>
                    <option value="Samoa">Samoa</option>
                    <option value="San Marino">San Marino</option>
                    <option value="Sao Tome and Principe">Sao Tome and Principe</option>
                    <option value="Saudi Arabia">Saudi Arabia</option>
                    <option value="Senegal">Senegal</option>
                    <option value="Serbia and Montenegro">Serbia and Montenegro</option>
                    <option value="Seychelles">Seychelles</option>
                    <option value="Sierra Leone">Sierra Leone</option>
                    <option value="Singapore">Singapore</option>
                    <option value="Slovakia">Slovakia</option>
                    <option value="Slovenia">Slovenia</option>
                    <option value="Solomon Islands">Solomon Islands</option>
                    <option value="Somalia">Somalia</option>
                    <option value="South Africa">South Africa</option>
                    <option value="South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands">South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands</option>
                    <option value="Sri Lanka">Sri Lanka</option>
                    <option value="Sudan">Sudan</option>
                    <option value="Suriname">Suriname</option>
                    <option value="Svalbard and Jan Mayen">Svalbard and Jan Mayen</option>
                    <option value="Swaziland">Swaziland</option>
                    <option value="Sweden">Sweden</option>
                    <option value="Switzerland">Switzerland</option>
                    <option value="Syrian Arab Republic">Syrian Arab Republic</option>
                    <option value="Taiwan">Taiwan</option>
                    <option value="Tajikistan">Tajikistan</option>
                    <option value="Tanzania, United Republic of">Tanzania, United Republic of</option>
                    <option value="Thailand">Thailand</option>
                    <option value="Timor-Leste">Timor-Leste</option>
                    <option value="Togo">Togo</option>
                    <option value="Tokelau">Tokelau</option>
                    <option value="Tonga">Tonga</option>
                    <option value="Trinidad and Tobago">Trinidad and Tobago</option>
                    <option value="Tunisia">Tunisia</option>
                    <option value="Turkey">Turkey</option>
                    <option value="Turkmenistan">Turkmenistan</option>
                    <option value="Turks and Caicos Islands">Turks and Caicos Islands</option>
                    <option value="Tuvalu">Tuvalu</option>
                    <option value="Uganda">Uganda</option>
                    <option value="Ukraine">Ukraine</option>
                    <option value="United Arab Emirates">United Arab Emirates</option>
                    <option value="United States Minor Outlying Islands">United States Minor Outlying Islands</option>
                    <option value="Uruguay">Uruguay</option>
                    <option value="Uzbekistan">Uzbekistan</option>
                    <option value="Vanuatu">Vanuatu</option>
                    <option value="Venezuela">Venezuela</option>
                    <option value="Viet Nam">Viet Nam</option>
                    <option value="Virgin Islands, British">Virgin Islands, British</option>
                    <option value="Virgin Islands, U.s.">Virgin Islands, U.s.</option>
                    <option value="Wallis and Futuna">Wallis and Futuna</option>
                    <option value="Western Sahara">Western Sahara</option>
                    <option value="Yemen">Yemen</option>
                    <option value="Zambia">Zambia</option>
                    <option value="Zimbabwe">Zimbabwe</option>
                </optgroup>
            </select>

        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="section">Some section</div>
</div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullPage.js/2.6.5/jquery.fullPage.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullPage.js/2.6.5/jquery.fullPage.css">
```

### 2nd try:

**Codepen**: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LVGoMY

Snippet:

**Doesn't work here as a snippet**

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#fullpage').fullpage({
        anchors: ["contact-form","contact"],
        navigation: true,
        scrollOverflow: true,
        navigationPosition: 'right',
        navigationTooltips: ["Form","Meh"],
        responsive: 991,
        easingcss3: 'cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.320, 1.275)',
        paddingTop: '110px',
        normalScrollElements: '#country'
    });
  
  $('#country').on('click', function(){$.fn.fullpage.setAllowScrolling(false);})
    $('#country').on('change', function(){$.fn.fullpage.setAllowScrolling(false, "all");})
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="fullpage">
    <div class="section">
        Some section
        <form action="">
            <select name="country" id="country" class="form-control" style="margin-top:20px;" data-fv-field="country">
                <option selected="" disabled="">Country</option>
                <optgroup label="Frequent Visitors">
                    <option value="France">France</option>
                    <option value="Germany">Germany</option>
                    <option value="Italy">Italy</option>
                    <option value="Norway">Norway</option>
                    <option value="Spain">Spain</option>
                    <option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option>
                    <option value="United States">United States</option>
                </optgroup>
                <optgroup label="All Countries">
                    <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
                    <option value="Albania">Albania</option>
                    <option value="Algeria">Algeria</option>
                    <option value="American Samoa">American Samoa</option>
                    <option value="Andorra">Andorra</option>
                    <option value="Angola">Angola</option>
                    <option value="Anguilla">Anguilla</option>
                    <option value="Antarctica">Antarctica</option>
                    <option value="Antigua and Barbuda">Antigua and Barbuda</option>
                    <option value="Argentina">Argentina</option>
                    <option value="Armenia">Armenia</option>
                    <option value="Aruba">Aruba</option>
                    <option value="Australia">Australia</option>
                    <option value="Austria">Austria</option>
                    <option value="Azerbaijan">Azerbaijan</option>
                    <option value="Bahamas">Bahamas</option>
                    <option value="Bahrain">Bahrain</option>
                    <option value="Bangladesh">Bangladesh</option>
                    <option value="Barbados">Barbados</option>
                    <option value="Belarus">Belarus</option>
                    <option value="Belgium">Belgium</option>
                    <option value="Belize">Belize</option>
                    <option value="Benin">Benin</option>
                    <option value="Czech Republic">Czech Republic</option>
                    <option value="Denmark">Denmark</option>
                    <option value="Djibouti">Djibouti</option>
                    <option value="Dominica">Dominica</option>
                    <option value="Dominican Republic">Dominican Republic</option>
                    <option value="Ecuador">Ecuador</option>
                    <option value="Egypt">Egypt</option>
                    <option value="El Salvador">El Salvador</option>
                    <option value="Equatorial Guinea">Equatorial Guinea</option>
                    <option value="Eritrea">Eritrea</option>
                    <option value="Estonia">Estonia</option>
                    <option value="Ethiopia">Ethiopia</option>
                    <option value="Falkland Islands (Malvinas)">Falkland Islands (Malvinas)</option>
                    <option value="Faroe Islands">Faroe Islands</option>
                    <option value="Fiji">Fiji</option>
                    <option value="Finland">Finland</option>
                    <option value="French Guiana">French Guiana</option>
                    <option value="French Polynesia">French Polynesia</option>
                    <option value="French Southern Territories">French Southern Territories</option>
                    <option value="Gabon">Gabon</option>
                    <option value="Gambia">Gambia</option>
                    <option value="Georgia">Georgia</option>
                    <option value="Ghana">Ghana</option>
                    <option value="Gibraltar">Gibraltar</option>
                    <option value="Greece">Greece</option>
                    <option value="Greenland">Greenland</option>
                    <option value="Grenada">Grenada</option>
                    <option value="Guadeloupe">Guadeloupe</option>
                    <option value="Guam">Guam</option>
                    <option value="Guatemala">Guatemala</option>
                    <option value="Guinea">Guinea</option>
                    <option value="Guinea-Bissau">Guinea-Bissau</option>
                    <option value="Guyana">Guyana</option>
                    <option value="Haiti">Haiti</option>
                    <option value="Heard Island and Mcdonald Islands">Heard Island and Mcdonald Islands</option>
                    <option value="Holy See (Vatican City State)">Holy See (Vatican City State)</option>
                    <option value="Honduras">Honduras</option>
                    <option value="Hong Kong">Hong Kong</option>
                    <option value="Hungary">Hungary</option>
                    <option value="Iceland">Iceland</option>
                    <option value="India">India</option>
                    <option value="Indonesia">Indonesia</option>
                    <option value="Iran, Islamic Republic of">Iran, Islamic Republic of</option>
                    <option value="Iraq">Iraq</option>
                    <option value="Ireland">Ireland</option>
                    <option value="Israel">Israel</option>
                    <option value="Jamaica">Jamaica</option>
                    <option value="Mali">Mali</option>
                    <option value="Malta">Malta</option>
                    <option value="Marshall Islands">Marshall Islands</option>
                    <option value="Martinique">Martinique</option>
                    <option value="Mauritania">Mauritania</option>
                    <option value="Mauritius">Mauritius</option>
                    <option value="Mayotte">Mayotte</option>
                    <option value="Mexico">Mexico</option>
                    <option value="Micronesia, Federated States of">Micronesia, Federated States of</option>
                    <option value="Moldova, Republic of">Moldova, Republic of</option>
                    <option value="Monaco">Monaco</option>
                    <option value="Mongolia">Mongolia</option>
                    <option value="Montserrat">Montserrat</option>
                    <option value="Morocco">Morocco</option>
                    <option value="Mozambique">Mozambique</option>
                    <option value="Myanmar">Myanmar</option>
                    <option value="Namibia">Namibia</option>
                    <option value="Nauru">Nauru</option>
                    <option value="Nepal">Nepal</option>
                    <option value="Netherlands">Netherlands</option>
                    <option value="Netherlands Antilles">Netherlands Antilles</option>
                    <option value="New Caledonia">New Caledonia</option>
                    <option value="New Zealand">New Zealand</option>
                    <option value="Nicaragua">Nicaragua</option>
                    <option value="Niger">Niger</option>
                    <option value="Nigeria">Nigeria</option>
                    <option value="Niue">Niue</option>
                    <option value="Panama">Panama</option>
                    <option value="Papua New Guinea">Papua New Guinea</option>
                </optgroup>
            </select>

        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="section">Some section</div>
</div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullPage.js/2.6.5/jquery.fullPage.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullPage.js/2.6.5/jquery.fullPage.css">
```

**`fullPage` doesn't work as a snippet**

So the question is, what am I missing? Or is this an issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your 2nd approach seems to be the way to go for it.
You should disable and enable the scrolling feature by detecting whether the user opens or closes the select box.

When you do this, make sure you are not using the option `normalScrollElements` as you are doing it now.

Also, whenever you enable or disable the scrolling feature, make sure to use the same function with the same arguments to prevent mistakes:

```
//enabling
$.fn.fullpage.setAllowScrolling(true);

//disabling
$.fn.fullpage.setAllowScrolling(false);

//vs the one you were using now
$.fn.fullpage.setAllowScrolling(false, "all");
```

Right now, I noticed in Chrome the `click` event gets fired even before `change` gets fired as well, which makes it a bit more tricky to deal with, but that's a matter of javascript rather than about fullPage.js.

If you manage to deal with the `click`, `focus` and `change` events in a proper way to detect whether the select box is opened or not, then you will have it working.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but so what's the difference between `false` and `false, "all"` as arguments ? gonna try this.

Comment: @JoelAlmeida that's just to avoid potential problems if there's any.

Comment: it worked perfectly, and also changed the way the events are being tracked. thanks.